# How the host's forward and backward DNS entries match in java application makes it secure from DNS spoofing

Tags: dns, fortify, java-security

I am using fortify and it is showing the vulnerability by which the attacker can do DNS spoofing while I am trying to get hostname in the java application. 
I have got one solution that by matching forward DNS and Reverse DNS entries it can be avoided. But how it is useful and how can I implement it, I am not able to find it. 
Fortify shows vulnerability at this line

[Link for line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHDyN.png)

Fortify is showing recommendations like this:

> Recommendations:
>
> You can increase confidence in a domain name lookup if you check to
>   make sure that the host's forward and backward DNS entries match. 
>   Attackers will not be able to spoof both the forward and the reverse
>   DNS entries without controlling the nameservers for the target domain.
>   This is not a foolproof approach however: attackers may be able to
>   convince the domain registrar to turn over the domain to a malicious
>   nameserver.  Basing authentication on DNS entries is simply a risky
>   proposition.

Any help is appreciated and another solutions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some efforts, what you had did

Comment: Sir thats what i am asking need the implementation method to do so.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with the **code** that causes the tool to alert, likely some operation using `InetAddress`.

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan  I have edited my question , if you got any solution then please do tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it's something like this:

```
    final String hostname = "google.com";
    final String ipAddress = "123.123.123.123";
    final InetAddress byIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    boolean forwardCheck = byIpAddress.getHostName().equals(hostname);
    final InetAddress byHostName = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    boolean reverseCheck = byHostName.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddress);
    if (reverseCheck && forwardCheck) {
        // perform your logic
    }
```